# Unlock ubuntu pc using my phone's fingerprint scanner

Tags: android, fingerprint-reader

My ideal app is something like MacID (http://macid.co/) but one that works with either iPhone or Android to unlock my ubuntu pc..

This offers some ways but they are limited to BT for linux. I want fingerprint.
http://www.howtogeek.com/222924/how-to-unlock-your-computer-with-your-phone-or-watch/

Comment: What is the question? Also what progress have you made? Also I am interested in collaborating, I am not an expert, though.

Comment: Well there is this app can perform "fingerprint actions", and can launch another app via the scanner... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ztc1997.fingerprint2sleep ... So, if someone here knows how to write an apk that can simply lauch a shell script that than executes ssh into your computer, as the user gnome (for example) if running as, than you could run  `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-screensaver-command -d` ... and that would unlock it.

Comment: You can try Tasker, it's able to run ssh commands, and it can run on an event. So maybe this will help.

Comment: I just want to make sure you're aware of how vulnerable your phone is, and by providing it access to your computer, you severely risk the computer's security.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? If my phone get hacked I'm in a terrible position anyway. You get access to my email, SMS and 2nd Factor apps... so you can literally reset ANY password for any account I own... that dwarfs the risk of unlocking my computer....

Answer (score 3):

I haven't yet tried it myself, but this cropped up in the past year:

https://github.com/maxchehab/remote-linux-unlocker

Essentially, install the software on your PC, [download the Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxchehab.remotelinuxunlocker) from the Play Store, then click the "lock" or "unlock" buttons on your phone, as required.

EDIT: Looks like the Android app has been removed from the play store, so this answer is no longer relevant.

Comment: The app isn't in the Play Store anymore.

Comment: True enough. The github is still up, but even the github link to the Play store is the same dead link I've posted in this answer. Looks like this is now dead in the water.